# Powershell to read excel and update metadata in different document library based on a cell value by matching the unique file name

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, document-library, excel, metadata

I have multiple libraries storing only document with unique name, site wise.

I need to update metadata for these uploaded documents based by reading an excel sheet.

The twist is that it updates metadata data in different document library based on a cell value in excel data.

Tried to achieve this via power automate but it takes eternity because of file count is huge in each upload around 2-3K.